# a private friend x a close friend

Tags: formality

What would be the best way to express intimacy with a friend?

A close friend = It would be a friend who doesn't like to talk about?

A private Friend = It would be a close friend?

I am very confused.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with the phrase *a private friend*: as far as I know, it is not used by native English speakers.

*A close friend* is a very common expression, and means a friend who is close (=near, not =closed), i.e. intimate.

Comment: @Lipeandarai Perhaps you mean 'a personal friend', which is commonly used, rather than 'private'? Have you heard 'a private friend' used? 'Personal' and 'private' could both be used,  for example when referring to a letter which is only for you and not for anyone else, but I agree with Colin - you would not normally hear 'a private friend' used by native speakers. You would use 'a personal friend' to indicate that you know someone - for example, you could tell someone "It's safe to buy a car from Colin, he's a personal friend."